# PHP: Replace Array Index Keys with Existing Unique Values

Tags: php, arrays

I queried my database and it stores the results into an array. It looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Submission_ID] => 111
        [First_Name] => Dylan
        [Last_Name] => Taylor
        [Abstract_Title] => Research 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Submission_ID] => 222
        [First_Name] => Michael
        [Last_Name] => Jones
        [Abstract_Title] => Research 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Submission_ID] => 333
        [First_Name] => Wills
        [Last_Name] => Adams
        [Abstract_Title] => Research 3
    )
)
```

This is all placed in a variable called `$results`. Currently, I'm displaying bits of data on my page like so:

```
echo $results[0][Abstract_Title]
```

It all works, however, it be convenient if the index keys were replaced with the Submission ID:

```
Array
(
[111] => Array
    (
        [Submission_ID] => 111
        [First_Name] => Dylan
        [Last_Name] => Taylor
        [Abstract_Title] => Research 1
    )

[222] => Array
    (
        [Submission_ID] => 222
        [First_Name] => Michael
        [Last_Name] => Jones
        [Abstract_Title] => Research 2
    )

[333] => Array
    (
        [Submission_ID] => 333
        [First_Name] => Wills
        [Last_Name] => Adams
        [Abstract_Title] => Research 3
    )
)
```

So I can do this instead (otherwise I would have to print the array just to look up the index key every time):

```
echo $results[111][Abstract_Title]
```

Any ideas? (I'm new to programming.) The closest answer I've found is: [php replace array id keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697548/php-replace-array-id-keys) but I can't get my head around the solution. I figured a `forloop` is the best option? Should the new array be placed in the same variable or new variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like as

```
$final_result = array_combine(array_column($result,'Submission_ID'),$result);
print_r($final_result);
```